# how to extract function name from a code string pythonic way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, string

I have a code string as follows

```
code = '\n        function factorial( n ){\n\n        let a=1;\n\t\tfor(let c=1; c<=n; c++){\n\ta=a*c;\n\t\t}\n\n\treturn a;\n        }\n\n\n    '
```

The name of the function is after function keyword and before the first '('. I know how to solve this problem but i was wondering whether there is a short pythonic way to extract function name from the given code string. I appreciate any insights. Thanks!

Comment: This is javascript source code?

Comment: Try using this: https://pypi.org/project/esprima/

Comment: If the code is always in the same structure, just use regex. Or you can do it natively with [`str.find()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find), it would be slightly faster but if you don't need that sort of optimization regex is just easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Potential approaches you can take (although neither of the ones below seem super pythonic) to match the function name:

If you have only one `function` in your string:

```
code = '\n        function factorial( n ){\n\n        let a=1;\n\t\tfor(let c=1; c<=n; c++){\n\ta=a*c;\n\t\t}\n\n\treturn a;\n        }\n\n\n    '

code.split('function ')[1].split('(')[0].strip()
```

Quick explanation:

- find `function`  then split the string into 2, and keep the second part of the string since that's the part which has the function name (we do this by accessing `[1]`)
- split this new string by an opening parenthesis `(` and keep the first match using `[0]`
- strip off any whitespace just in case there's a space between the function name and the parenthesis, e.g. `function my_function ()...` instead of `function my_function()...`

Generalized approach to capture multiple `function`s:

```
import re

code = '\n        function factorial( n ){\n\n        let a=1;\n\t\tfor(let c=1; c<=n; c++){\n\ta=a*c;\n\t\t}\n\n\treturn a;\n        }\n\n\n    \n        function factorial( n ){\n\n        let a=1;\n\t\tfor(let c=1; c<=n; c++){\n\ta=a*c;\n\t\t}\n\n\treturn a;\n        }\n\n\n    \n        function factorial( n ){\n\n        let a=1;\n\t\tfor(let c=1; c<=n; c++){\n\ta=a*c;\n\t\t}\n\n\treturn a;\n        }\n\n\n    \n        function factorial( n ){\n\n        let a=1;\n\t\tfor(let c=1; c<=n; c++){\n\ta=a*c;\n\t\t}\n\n\treturn a;\n        }\n\n\n    '

re.findall('function (.+?)\s?\(', code)
```

Quick explanation:

- `re` is python's regular expression module, and allows you to capture text based on specified strings
- `'function (.+?)\s?\('` tells the regular expression module to look for

  - `function`
  - followed by a space
  - followed by any characters ([the `.` metacharacter](https://regular-expressions.mobi/dot.html?wlr=1) matches most characters other than a line break)
  - up UNTIL an optional space `\s?` (the `\s` is a special character matching any space character, and the `?` indicates this character is optional)
  - followed by an opening parenthesis `(`

Comment: thank you. this was simple to understand and worked well.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you always expect the `function` keyword to be present, use `re.findall` here:

```py
code = '\n        function factorial( n ){\n\n        let a=1;\n\t\tfor(let c=1; c<=n; c++){\n\ta=a*c;\n\t\t}\n\n\treturn a;\n        }\n\n\n    '
func_names = re.findall(r'\bfunction\s+(\S+?)\s*\(', code)
print(func_names)  # ['factorial']
```